# How to extract invoice number between - deliminiters

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Invoice numbers can contain 1 or minus characters in beginnig and 1 or more  -n version numbers in end.
How to extract main part of invoice number ? 
For this leading - characters should stripped and trailing -n variants should also stripped.

For example

```
 1002546556
 -1002546556
 ---1002546556
 1002546556-1-K
 -1002546556-2
 --1002546556-2-3
```

for all those numbers result should be

```
1002546556
```

I tried

```
select regexp_replace(invoicenumber, '-.*', '', 'g') from invoice
```

but if invoice number starts with - , it returns empty value.

Using

PostgreSQL 9.3.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit

Comment: @CarySwoveland The greying out is done automatically for things starting with `--` by the stack overflow system, as it detects it as a comment.  He cannot control that independently from the data itself

Comment: @jjanes, thank you for clarifying that. I read (evidently misread), "Invoice numbers can contain 1 or minus characters in beginning..." as "Invoice numbers can contain a `1` or a minus character in beginning...". Andrus, I suggest you clarify your first sentence to something like "...can begin with a `"1"` or one or more hyphens...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for regular expressions really.   This will do for example:
`select split_part(ltrim(invoicenumber,'-'),'-',1)`

Comment: ltrim(invoicenumber,'-') trims all leading '-' .  I'm not sure if the lines are intentionally greyed or if it's due to the fact that it's comment in sql and somehow got pasted in.

Comment: I was mistaken. See my comment on the question. If you will delete your comment I will  then delete this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_match()`:

```
select (regexp_match('1002546556-1-K', '[0-9]+'))[1]
```

This returns the first string of digits in the the string.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=aaaf1c467ba2c52634e1ca042a3911d2) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Odd. I thought I had deleted my comment earlier and added one to the effect that I evidently had misunderstood the question, referencing my comment on the question, and suggested you remove your comment. When I see it's gone I'll know you've read this and will delete this comment.